# Turn j# applet to winform user control

Tags: winforms, j#

I have a java applet written in J#
Is there any way to turn this applet into Winforms Custom Control?

Comment: Yes, the hard way. Serious: [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/open-source-projects/code-converter/j-to-c-vb-conversion.aspx) is a popular link. I don't consider this an answer because I never tried. Would be nice if you could share your solution in due time, even if in the end it turns out you have to do it all by yourself.

Comment: My problem is with the interface differences between JApplet and Forms.CustomControl some internal objects use "this" to access their host and the properties and methods are different